# Python: Decoding base64 encoded strings

Tags: python, base64

I'm new to python and have a question about decoding base64 encoded urls:

```
import base64
url64="aHR0cDovLzR1ZnJlZS50ay9tZWRpYTcyMzY0Ni9mdWVuZi8wMzYubXAzA"
finalUrl=base64.b64decode(url64)
```

Won't work! TypeError: Incorrect padding

I've also tried to add the needed padding:

```
import base64
url64="aHR0cDovLzR1ZnJlZS50ay9tZWRpYTcyMzY0Ni9mdWVuZi8wMzYubXAzA"
finalUrl=base64.b64decode(url64 + '=' * (4 - len(url64) % 4))
```

but im still getting TypeError: Incorrect padding

Would be great if someone knows a solution for this.

Comment: Why it should work? Where did you get this string?

Comment: Other base64 encoded URLs were working fine... I got it from scraping a website!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It would appear that the final `A` is superfluous:

```
In [4]: base64.b64decode('aHR0cDovLzR1ZnJlZS50ay9tZWRpYTcyMzY0Ni9mdWVuZi8wMzYubXAz')
Out[4]: 'http://4ufree.tk/media723646/fuenf/036.mp3'
```

Comment: Thanks! So I have to figure out when to add padding and when to remove superfluous chars...

Comment: No, if you've got unwanted characters on the end of your base64 string, what you have there is corrupted data. That string is not valid base64, and there's no way to fix it without knowing what it was supposed to be in the first place. Where did you get it?